# jQuery noob: $("this").parent().attr("id",newId); troubles

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code which I am trying to change the ID of on.hover.

```
<span id="slidingProd">
    <a href="{link controller=order action=addToCart id=$product.ID returnPath=true}" rel="nofollow" class="addToCart" title="Bestill"
     onclick="addToBasket(); return false;" id="fly_to_basket">&nbsp;</a>
</span>
```

I tried to use this jQuery, but it doesn't change the ID.

```
$(function() {
    $("#fly_to_basket").hover(function() {
      $(this).parent().attr("id",slidingprod(1));

});
    $("#fly_to_basket").hover(function() {
      $(this).attr("onclick",addToBasket(1));
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks :)

Comment: What does `slidingprod(1)` return?

Comment: I just need to change the id from `slidingprod` to `slidingprod(1)`

Comment: What does `slidingprod(1)` return?  Are you getting any errors? Is there a specific reason you want to change the `id` attribute, it seems a bit unorthodox.

Comment: It's for a fly-to-basket function. It only works with unique Ids, but the page is dynamically generated. So if I can have the id change on hover, the other function will work properly.

Comment: You are calling slidingprod() function with parameter '1'. So you either have that function defined somewhere and it returns a string or  that statement is **totally** wrong

Comment: @  Botondus: thanks, I didn't know that..

Comment: how does addToBasket() code look like?

Comment: You can see it here: http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/index.html?whichScript=fly-to-basket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by your comment

> *I just need to change the id from slidingprod to slidingprod(1)*

1. Brackets aren't valid characters for ID strings. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name:

   > ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").
2. You haven't enclosed the new ID in a string.

ex:

```
$(this).parent().attr("id","slidingprod-1");
```

Comment: I thought this might be it... If you don't enclose the new ID in a string then it's parsed as JavaScript, and `slidingprod(1)` in JavaScript means "call the slidingprod() function with an argument of 1".

Comment: I think that this solution won't work then if I can't use brackets as a simple replace as `Botondus` said. Thanks for cleaning up my jQuery code. I don'y know how to implement this then.

Answer (score 2):

$(this)..... Not $("this")

Comment: Duh.. Thanks, that's one problem I guess but it still doesn't change the ID.

Answer (score 0):

Does `$("this")` work with quotes? I think `$(this)` is better.

Anyway, I don't like changing ID's at runtime. Seems messy...